# Transform pandas dataframe as per the image below

Tags: python, pandas, stack, pivot, unpivot

Please help me understand what will be the best way to do the transformation of pandas DataFrame in the image shown below.

```
dct = {'section': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3},
 'friendly': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 5, 8: 5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

5 : Excellent
4 : Very Good
3 : Good
2 : Just Okay
1 : Poor

INPUT :

[image]

OUTPUT :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for count, then get percentages to `df2` by divide by `sum`, join by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` for `MultiIndex`, sorting it and flatten in `map`:

```
d = {5 : 'Excellent', 4 : 'Very Good', 3 : 'Good', 2 : 'Just Okay', 1 : 'Poor'}

df1 = pd.crosstab(df['section'], df['friendly'])
df2 = df1.div(df1.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).round().astype(int)

df = (pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=('Count','Per'), axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[False, True], level=[1,0])
        .rename(columns=d))

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   section  Excellent_Count  Excellent_Per  Very Good_Count  Very Good_Per  \
0        1                3             75                1             25   
1        2                0              0                0              0   
2        3                2             67                0              0   

   Good_Count  Good_Per  Just Okay_Count  Just Okay_Per  Poor_Count  Poor_Per  
0           0         0                0              0           0         0  
1           1        50                0              0           1        50  
2           0         0                1             33           0         0
```